# CoreML automatic cast int to float

Tags: swift, coreml, coremltools

I am new user of coremltool, currently I am able to convert my TF model, and run it in python. However the output layer of my model is [automatically converted](https://github.com/apple/coremltools/blob/0d38c5a95c0d9d53451df6282f934e1f9c7c4e84/coremltools/converters/mil/backend/nn/passes/alert_return_type_cast.py) to float instead of int32. I have to perform myself in python a rollback conversion.

```
model.predict({"Input": image}).astype(int)
```

Does somebody knows how to cancel this automatic conversion ? And keep my output as a multidimensional array - int ?

Thank you,

++t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the datatype of the model's outputs to INT32 using the coremltools Python library. That will automatically cast those numbers from floats to integers.

Something like this:

```
import coremltools
model = coremltools.models.MLModel("YourModel.mlmodel")
spec = model._spec
spec.description.output[0].type.multiArrayType.dataType = coremltools.proto.FeatureTypes_pb2.ArrayFeatureType.INT32
coremltools.models.utils.save_spec(spec, "YourNewModel.mlmodel")
```

The reason this is not done automatically, is because usually floats are the correct datatype.

Comment: Thank you, and your book is good. I bought last week.